# MeanShift or bandwith estimator taking too long to cluster points of and image

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

I am not sure if it is the bandwith estimator or Meanshift that is taking ages, I want to know how i can reduce the time, maybe I need to modify the image or maybe the parameters of the the clustering algo.

THIS IS THE IMAGE:
[image]

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MeanShift, DBSCAN, AgglomerativeClustering # KMeans, MeanShift, DBSCAN y AgglomerativeHierarchicalClustering
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture # GaussianMixture
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = Image.open("/kaggle/input/kid-draw/drawings.jpg")
gray = ImageOps.grayscale(image)

data = np.asarray(gray)
points = []
maxX = len(data)
maxY = len(data[0])
for i in range(maxX):
    for j in range(maxY):
        if data[i][j] < 125:
            points.append((-i, j))

points = np.array(points)
plt.scatter(points[:, 1], points[:, 0])
plt.show()
print(points)

kernel = sklearn.cluster.estimate_bandwidth(points)
ms = MeanShift(bandwith=kernel)
clusters = ms.fit_predict(points)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the original image is quite large. I would consider to resize it first:

[openCV resize](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

```
import cv2
 
img = cv2.imread("/kaggle/input/kid-draw/drawings.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
resized = cv2.resize(img, (80,80), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

The resulting image will also be a np.array.